# Woocommerce get product category base permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to retrieve the product category base permalink?

Thanx.

**EDIT**

I'm adding this image as an example:
[image]

i'm looking for a `get_?option?('?product-category-base?')` kind of function, in this example it should return *only* the string: `whatever`.

**EDIT 2**

The image i posted is a crop from `wordpress dashboard` -> `Settings` -> `Permalink` and indicates the `additional settings` -> `product-category-base`.
I need to retrive the value eventually inserted by admins in the field `Product category base`, i guess there is a key for a kind of `get_option()` function...


Thanx.

Answer (score 10):

This is (presumably) too late for the OP, but if anyone else comes across it, the option you want is `woocommerce_permalinks`, and within that the `category_base` key.

Minimal example (without any checks, etc):

```
$wc_options = get_option('woocommerce_permalinks');
$product_category_base = $wc_options['category_base'];
```

Comment: Do you happen to know, if combined with WPML, where one could find the base for the current language?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Then you are looking for the category?
At least that explain in the Woocommerce official site

> The default category base is product-category. An example would be
>   yourdomain.com/product-category/category-name.

You can get the category (or categories) of a product with:

```
global $product; 
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', ' ' . _n( ' ', '  ', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ' ' );
```

> Original Post

I don't think I understand your question.
Do you mean this permalink?

```
echo $Permalink=$product->get_permalink();
```

That return this (I edited to omit my site).

```
http://mysiteurl.com/product/4-pack/
```

I'm not sure what do you want to do with that? Can you explain more?

Comment: thanx for the answer, i just updated my question with an image and a kind of pseudo-function-name i'm looking for

Comment: I see. Ok. I edited my answer to what I think you are looking for

Comment: This is not related to products, i cannot neither try the solution you suggested in your edit. I edited my question again, see EDIT 2. Thanx.